# Detecting whether a GPS coordinate falls within a polygon on a map

Tags: math, geolocation, gps, coordinates, geospatial

As stated in the title, the goal is to have a way for detecting whether a given GPS coordinate falls inside a polygon or not.

The polygon itself can be either convex or concave. It's defined as a set of edge vectors and a known point within that polygon. Each edge vector is further defined by four coordinates which are the **latitudes and longitudes** of respective tip points and a bearing relative to the starting point.

There are a couple of questions similar to this one here on StackOverflow but they describe the solution only in general terms and for a 2D plane, whereas I am looking for an existing implementation that supports polygons defined by latitude/longitude pairs in [WGS 84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS_84).

What API-s or services are out there for doing such collision tests?

Comment: Are your polygons defined by lines that are great circle segments, or are they defined by lines that are points of constant latitude/longitude?

Answer (score 41):

**Here is a java program which uses a function that will return true if a latitude/longitude is found inside of a polygon defined by a list of lat/longs, with demonstration for the state of florida.**

I'm not sure if it deals with the fact that the lat/long GPS system is not an x/y coordinate plane.  For my uses I have demonstrated that it works (I think if you specify enough points in the bounding box, it washes away the effect that the earth is a sphere, and that straight lines between two points on the earth is not an arrow straight line.

First specify the points that make up the corner points of the polygon, it can have concave and convex corners.  The coordinates I use below traces the perimeter of the state of Florida.

method `coordinate_is_inside_polygon` utilizes an algorithm I don't quite understand.  Here is an official explanation from the source where I got it:

"... solution forwarded by Philippe Reverdy is to compute the sum of the angles made between the test point and each pair of points making up the polygon. If this sum is 2pi then the point is an interior point, if 0 then the point is an exterior point. This also works for polygons with holes given the polygon is defined with a path made up of coincident edges into and out of the hole as is common practice in many CAD packages. "

My unit tests show it does work reliably, even when the bounding box is a 'C' shape or even shaped like a [Torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus).  (My unit tests test many points inside Florida and make sure the function returns true.  And I pick a number of coordinates everywhere else in the world and make sure it returns false.  I pick places all over the world which might confuse it.

I'm not sure this will work if the polygon bounding box crosses the equator, prime meridian, or any area where the coordinates change from -180 -> 180, -90 -> 90. Or your polygon wraps around the earth around the north/south poles.  For me, I only need it to work for the perimeter of Florida.  If you have to define a polygon that spans the earth or crosses these lines, you could work around it by making two polygons, one representing the area on one side of the meridian and one representing the area on the other side and testing if your point is in either of those points.

Here is where I found this algorithm: [Determining if a point lies on the interior of a polygon - Solution 2](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/#insidepoly)

Run it for yourself to double check it.

**Put this in a file called Runner.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Runner
{
    public static double PI = 3.14159265;
    public static double TWOPI = 2*PI;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> lat_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> long_array = new ArrayList<Double>();

    //This is the polygon bounding box, if you plot it, 
    //you'll notice it is a rough tracing of the parameter of 
    //the state of Florida starting at the upper left, moving 
    //clockwise, and finishing at the upper left corner of florida.

    ArrayList<String> polygon_lat_long_pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("31.000213,-87.584839");  
    //lat/long of upper left tip of florida.
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("31.009629,-85.003052");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.726726,-84.838257");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.584962,-82.168579");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.73617,-81.476441");  
    //lat/long of upper right tip of florida.
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.002375,-80.795288");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("26.896598,-79.938355");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("25.813738,-80.059204");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.93028,-80.454712");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.401135,-81.817017");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.700927,-81.959839");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.950203,-81.124878");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("26.0015,-82.014771");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("27.833247,-83.014527");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("28.8389,-82.871704");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.987293,-84.091187");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.539053,-85.134888");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.272352,-86.47522");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.281839,-87.628784");

    //Convert the strings to doubles.       
    for(String s : polygon_lat_long_pairs){
        lat_array.add(Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[0]));
        long_array.add(Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]));
    }

   //prints TRUE true because the lat/long passed in is
    //inside the bounding box.
    System.out.println(coordinate_is_inside_polygon(
            25.7814014D,-80.186969D,
            lat_array, long_array));

    //prints FALSE because the lat/long passed in 
    //is Not inside the bounding box.
    System.out.println(coordinate_is_inside_polygon(
            25.831538D,-1.069338D, 
            lat_array, long_array));

}
public static boolean coordinate_is_inside_polygon(
    double latitude, double longitude, 
    ArrayList<Double> lat_array, ArrayList<Double> long_array)
{       
       int i;
       double angle=0;
       double point1_lat;
       double point1_long;
       double point2_lat;
       double point2_long;
       int n = lat_array.size();

       for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
          point1_lat = lat_array.get(i) - latitude;
          point1_long = long_array.get(i) - longitude;
          point2_lat = lat_array.get((i+1)%n) - latitude; 
          //you should have paid more attention in high school geometry.
          point2_long = long_array.get((i+1)%n) - longitude;
          angle += Angle2D(point1_lat,point1_long,point2_lat,point2_long);
       }

       if (Math.abs(angle) < PI)
          return false;
       else
          return true;
}

public static double Angle2D(double y1, double x1, double y2, double x2)
{
   double dtheta,theta1,theta2;

   theta1 = Math.atan2(y1,x1);
   theta2 = Math.atan2(y2,x2);
   dtheta = theta2 - theta1;
   while (dtheta > PI)
      dtheta -= TWOPI;
   while (dtheta < -PI)
      dtheta += TWOPI;

   return(dtheta);
}

public static boolean is_valid_gps_coordinate(double latitude, 
    double longitude)
{
    //This is a bonus function, it's unused, to reject invalid lat/longs.
    if (latitude > -90 && latitude < 90 && 
            longitude > -180 && longitude < 180)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

**Demon magic needs to be unit-tested.  Put this in a file called MainTest.java to verify it works for you**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MainTest {
@Test
public void test_lat_long_in_bounds(){
    Runner r = new Runner();
    //These make sure the lat/long passed in is a valid gps 
    //lat/long coordinate.  These should be valid. 
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(25, -82));
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(-25, -82));
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(25, 82));
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(-25, 82));
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(0, 0));
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(89, 179));
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(-89, -179));
    assertTrue(r.is_valid_gps_coordinate(89.999, 179));
    //If your bounding box crosses the equator or prime meridian, 
    then you have to test for those situations still work.
}
@Test
public void realTest_for_points_inside()
{
    ArrayList<Double> lat_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> long_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> polygon_lat_long_pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
    //upper left tip of florida.
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("31.000213,-87.584839");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("31.009629,-85.003052");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.726726,-84.838257");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.584962,-82.168579");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.73617,-81.476441");  
    //upper right tip of florida.
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.002375,-80.795288");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("26.896598,-79.938355");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("25.813738,-80.059204");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.93028,-80.454712");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.401135,-81.817017");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.700927,-81.959839");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.950203,-81.124878");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("26.0015,-82.014771");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("27.833247,-83.014527");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("28.8389,-82.871704");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.987293,-84.091187");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.539053,-85.134888");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.272352,-86.47522");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.281839,-87.628784");

    for(String s : polygon_lat_long_pairs){
        lat_array.add(Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[0]));
        long_array.add(Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]));
    }

    Runner r = new Runner();
    ArrayList<String> pointsInside = new ArrayList<String>();
    pointsInside.add("30.82112,-87.255249");
    pointsInside.add("30.499804,-86.8927");
    pointsInside.add("29.96826,-85.036011");
    pointsInside.add("30.490338,-83.981323");
    pointsInside.add("29.825395,-83.344116");
    pointsInside.add("30.215406,-81.828003");
    pointsInside.add("29.299813,-82.728882");
    pointsInside.add("28.540135,-81.212769");
    pointsInside.add("27.92065,-82.619019");
    pointsInside.add("28.143691,-81.740113");
    pointsInside.add("27.473186,-80.718384");
    pointsInside.add("26.769154,-81.729126");
    pointsInside.add("25.853292,-80.223999");
    pointsInside.add("25.278477,-80.707398");
    pointsInside.add("24.571105,-81.762085");   //bottom tip of keywest
    pointsInside.add("24.900388,-80.663452");
    pointsInside.add("24.680963,-81.366577");

    for(String s : pointsInside)
    {
        assertTrue(r.coordinate_is_inside_polygon(
            Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[0]), 
            Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]), 
            lat_array, long_array));
    }
}

@Test
public void realTest_for_points_outside()
{
    ArrayList<Double> lat_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> long_array = new ArrayList<Double>();

    ArrayList<String> polygon_lat_long_pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
    //upper left tip, florida.
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("31.000213,-87.584839");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("31.009629,-85.003052");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.726726,-84.838257");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.584962,-82.168579");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.73617,-81.476441");
    //upper right tip, florida.
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.002375,-80.795288");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("26.896598,-79.938355");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("25.813738,-80.059204");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.93028,-80.454712");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.401135,-81.817017");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.700927,-81.959839");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("24.950203,-81.124878");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("26.0015,-82.014771");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("27.833247,-83.014527");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("28.8389,-82.871704");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.987293,-84.091187");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("29.539053,-85.134888");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.272352,-86.47522");
    polygon_lat_long_pairs.add("30.281839,-87.628784");

    for(String s : polygon_lat_long_pairs)
    {
        lat_array.add(Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[0]));
        long_array.add(Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]));
    }

    Runner r = new Runner();

    ArrayList<String> pointsOutside = new ArrayList<String>();
    pointsOutside.add("31.451159,-87.958374");
    pointsOutside.add("31.319856,-84.607544");
    pointsOutside.add("30.868282,-84.717407");
    pointsOutside.add("31.338624,-81.685181");
    pointsOutside.add("29.452991,-80.498657");
    pointsOutside.add("26.935783,-79.487915");
    pointsOutside.add("25.159207,-79.916382");
    pointsOutside.add("24.311058,-81.17981");
    pointsOutside.add("25.149263,-81.838989");
    pointsOutside.add("27.726326,-83.695679");
    pointsOutside.add("29.787263,-87.024536");
    pointsOutside.add("29.205877,-62.102052");
    pointsOutside.add("14.025751,-80.690919");
    pointsOutside.add("29.029276,-90.805666");
    pointsOutside.add("-12.606032,-70.151369");
    pointsOutside.add("-56.520716,-172.822269");
    pointsOutside.add("-75.89666,9.082024");
    pointsOutside.add("-24.078567,142.675774");
    pointsOutside.add("84.940737,177.480462");
    pointsOutside.add("47.374545,9.082024");
    pointsOutside.add("25.831538,-1.069338");
    pointsOutside.add("0,0");

    for(String s : pointsOutside){
        assertFalse(r.coordinate_is_inside_polygon(
            Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[0]),
            Double.parseDouble(s.split(",")[1]), lat_array, long_array));
    }
}
}
//The list of lat/long inside florida bounding box all return true.
//The list of lat/long outside florida bounding box all return false.
```

I used eclipse IDE to get this to run java using java 1.6.0.  For me all the unit tests pass.  You need to include the junit 4 jar file in your classpath or import it into Eclipse.

Comment: Works perfect for me! Thanks for the demo and explanation.

Comment: Useful code I've translated to c# and works perfectly thanks!

Comment: @FernandoAguilar It can be useful if you publish the C# version.

Comment: I think the picture in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43822141/2234161 explains why the formula works.

Comment: Working like a charm...Thanks for the solution. @Eric

Answer (score 5):

I thought similarly as shab first (his proposal is called [Ray-Casting Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm)), but had second thoughts like Spacedman:

> ...but all the geometry will have to be redone in spherical coordinates...

I implemented and tested the mathematically correct way of doing that, e.i. intersecting great circles and determining whether one of the two intersecting points is on both arcs. (Note: I followed the steps described [here](http://www.boeing-727.com/Data/fly%20odds/distance.html#arc2), but I found several errors: The `sign` function is missing at the end of step 6 (just before `arcsin`), and the final test is numerical garbage (as subtraction is badly conditioned); use rather `L_1T >= max(L_1a, L_1b)` to test whether S1 is on the first arc etc.)

That also is **extremely slow and a numerical nightmare** (evaluates ~100 trigonometric functions, among other things); it proved not to be usable in our embedded systems.

**There's a trick, though**: If the area you are considering is small enough, just do a standard cartographic projection, e.g. [spherical Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection#Formulae_for_the_spherical_transverse_Mercator), of each point:

```
// latitude, longitude in radians
x = longitude;
y = log(tan(pi/4 + latitude/2));
```

Then, you can apply ray-casting, where the intersection of arcs is checked by  this function:

```
public bool ArcsIntersecting(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, 
  double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
    {

    double vx1 = x2 - x1;
    double vy1 = y2 - y1;

    double vx2 = x4 - x3;
    double vy2 = y4 - y3;

    double denom = vx1 * vy2 - vx2 * vy1;

    if (denom == 0) { return false; } // edges are parallel

    double t1 = (vx2 * (y1 - y3) - vy2 * (x1 - x3)) / denom;

    double t2;

    if (vx2 != 0) { t2 = (x1 - x3 + t1 * vx1) / vx2; }
    else if (vy2 != 0) { t2 = (y1 - y3 + t1 * vy1) / vy2; }
    else { return false; } // edges are matching

    return min(t1, t2) >= 0 && max(t1, t2) <= 1;
}
```

Comment: "// latitude, longitude in radians" does this mean that I need to convert lat/long in radians and then apply those formulas, or are those the formulas to convert them?

Comment: Found the formula in the paper you linked: radians = degrees × 0.0174533

Answer (score 4):

If you have WGS84 coordinates on the sphere, then your polygon divides the sphere into two areas - how do we know which area is 'inside' and which is 'outside' the polygon? The question is essentially meaningless!

For example, suppose the polygon formed the line of the equator - is the Northern hemisphere 'in' or 'out'?

Comment: Although this answer should rather be a comment, it does make a valid point. I updated the question to resolve the ambiguity. Do you have any suggestions on the API side?

Comment: To test if a point is in the same polygon as another point you just need to test if a line between the points intersects an odd or even number of polygon segments. However, polygon segments on a sphere are not uniquely defined by two pairs of lat-long coordinates since great circle arcs connecting those points can go either of two ways. Normally you'd expect to use the shortest route, but that ain't necessarily so if you want a fully generic solution. Anyway, the best thing for geography ops is probably PostGIS.

Comment: Indeed. Defining an azimuth for each polygon segment will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

From memory, the way to determine whether a point lies within a polygon is to imagine drawing a line from the position to some far away point. You then count the number of intersections between the line and the line segments of the polygon. If it count is even, then it does not lie within the polygon. If it is false, then it does lie within the polygon.

Comment: Is there a way you could show an example of how to do this using these points? `41.21,-104.77`(point to check) then I have polygon points (`39.39 -101.69 + 48.8335,-106.2435 + 38.803,-109.5781 + 39.4413,-111.043 + 45.6336,-113.7162 + 48.8335,-106.2435`) **in pseudo code will work!**

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript Version -**

```js
{
const PI = 3.14159265;
const TWOPI = 2*PI;
function isCoordinateInsidePitch(latitude, longitude, latArray, longArray)
{       
       let angle=0;
       let p1Lat;
       let p1Long;
       let p2Lat;
       let p2Long;
       let n = latArray.length;

       for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          p1Lat = latArray[i] - latitude;
          p1Long = longArray[i] - longitude;
          p2Lat = latArray[(i+1)%n] - latitude;
          p2Long = longArray[(i+1)%n] - longitude;
          angle += angle2D(p1Lat,p1Long,p2Lat,p2Long);
       }

       return !(Math.abs(angle) < PI);
}

function angle2D(y1, x1, y2, x2)
{
   let dtheta,theta1,theta2;

   theta1 = Math.atan2(y1,x1);
   theta2 = Math.atan2(y2,x2);
   dtheta = theta2 - theta1;
   while (dtheta > PI)
      dtheta -= TWOPI;
   while (dtheta < -PI)
      dtheta += TWOPI;

   return dtheta;
}

function isValidCoordinate(latitude,longitude)
{
    return (
    latitude !== '' && longitude !== '' && !isNaN(latitude) 
     && !isNaN(longitude) && latitude > -90 &&
     latitude < 90 && longitude > -180 && longitude < 180
     )
}
let latArray = [32.10458, 32.10479, 32.1038, 32.10361];
let longArray = [34.86448, 34.86529, 34.86563, 34.86486];
// true
console.log(isCoordinateInsidePitch(32.104447, 34.865108,latArray, longArray));
// false
// isCoordinateInsidePitch(32.104974, 34.864576,latArray, longArray);
// true
// isValidCoordinate(0, 0)
// true
// isValidCoordinate(32.104974, 34.864576)
}
```

Comment: It does not work for polygon, maybe only for rectangle. Test data... let latArray = [32.10458, 32.10479, 32.1038, 32.10361, 32.104447];
let longArray = [34.86448, 34.86529, 34.86563, 34.86486, 34.866]; test point: 32.10456, 34.86552 is inside, but your code returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you handle the case of wrapping around the meridian and crossing the equator (by adding offsets)  - can't you just treat this as a simple 2d point in polygon ?

Comment: Sort of, but you can't treat a line between (a,b) to (c,d) as straight (in other words it doesn't pass through ((a+c)/2,(b+d)/2)) so the usual 2d p-i-p algorithms in Euclidean space won't work. The *methods* of those algorithms can be applied, but all the geometry will have to be redone in spherical coordinates (things like computing line crossings).

Comment: @Spacedman: that depends on if Saul is using great-circle line segments or constant lat/long line segments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm written in Go:
It takes point coordinates in [lat,long] format and polygon in format [[lat,long],[lat,long]...]. Algorithm will join the first and last point in the polygon slice

```
import "math"

// ContainsLocation determines whether the point is inside the polygon
func ContainsLocation(point []float64, polygon [][]float64, geodesic 
   bool) bool {
    size := len(polygon)
    if size == 0 {
        return false
    }

    var (
        lat2, lng2, dLng3 float64
    )

    lat3 := toRadians(point[0])
    lng3 := toRadians(point[1])
    prev := polygon[size-1]
    lat1 := toRadians(prev[0])
    lng1 := toRadians(prev[1])
    nIntersect := 0

    for _, v := range polygon {
        dLng3 = wrap(lng3-lng1, -math.Pi, math.Pi)
        // Special case: point equal to vertex is inside.
        if lat3 == lat1 && dLng3 == 0 {
            return true
        }
        lat2 = toRadians(v[0])
        lng2 = toRadians(v[1])
        // Offset longitudes by -lng1.
        if intersects(lat1, lat2, wrap(lng2-lng1, -math.Pi, math.Pi), lat3, dLng3, geodesic) {
            nIntersect++
        }
        lat1 = lat2
        lng1 = lng2
    }

    return (nIntersect & 1) != 0
}

func toRadians(p float64) float64 {
    return p * (math.Pi / 180.0)
}

func wrap(n, min, max float64) float64 {
    if n >= min && n < max {
        return n
    }
    return mod(n-min, max-min) + min
}

func mod(x, m float64) float64 {
    return math.Remainder(math.Remainder(x, m)+m, m)
}

func intersects(lat1, lat2, lng2, lat3, lng3 float64, geodesic bool) bool {
    // Both ends on the same side of lng3.
    if (lng3 >= 0 && lng3 >= lng2) || (lng3 < 0 && lng3 < lng2) {
        return false
    }
    // Point is South Pole.
    if lat3 <= -math.Pi/2 {
        return false
    }
    // Any segment end is a pole.
    if lat1 <= -math.Pi/2 || lat2 <= -math.Pi/2 || lat1 >= math.Pi/2 || lat2 >= math.Pi/2 {
        return false
    }
    if lng2 <= -math.Pi {
        return false
    }
    linearLat := (lat1*(lng2-lng3) + lat2*lng3) / lng2
    // Northern hemisphere and point under lat-lng line.
    if lat1 >= 0 && lat2 >= 0 && lat3 < linearLat {
        return false
    }
    // Southern hemisphere and point above lat-lng line.
    if lat1 <= 0 && lat2 <= 0 && lat3 >= linearLat {
        return true
    }
    // North Pole.
    if lat3 >= math.Pi/2 {
        return true
    }

    // Compare lat3 with latitude on the GC/Rhumb segment corresponding to lng3.
    // Compare through a strictly-increasing function (tan() or mercator()) as convenient.
    if geodesic {
        return math.Tan(lat3) >= tanLatGC(lat1, lat2, lng2, lng3)
    }
    return mercator(lat3) >= mercatorLatRhumb(lat1, lat2, lng2, lng3)
}

func tanLatGC(lat1, lat2, lng2, lng3 float64) float64 {
    return (math.Tan(lat1)*math.Sin(lng2-lng3) + math.Tan(lat2)*math.Sin(lng3)) / math.Sin(lng2)
}

func mercator(lat float64) float64 {
    return math.Log(math.Tan(lat*0.5 + math.Pi/4))
}

func mercatorLatRhumb(lat1, lat2, lng2, lng3 float64) float64 {
    return (mercator(lat1)*(lng2-lng3) + mercator(lat2)*lng3) / lng2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Runner.Java code in VB.NET

For the benefit of .NET folks the same code is put in VB.NET.  Have tried it and is quite fast. Tried with 350000 records, it finishes in just few minutes.
But as said by author, i'm yet to test scenarios intersecting equator, multizones etc.

'Usage

```
If coordinate_is_inside_polygon(CurLat, CurLong, Lat_Array, Long_Array) Then
    MsgBox("Location " & CurLat & "," & CurLong & " is within polygon boundary")
Else
    MsgBox("Location " & CurLat & "," & CurLong & " is NOT within polygon boundary")
End If
```

'Functions

```
Public Function coordinate_is_inside_polygon(ByVal latitude As Double, ByVal longitude As Double, ByVal lat_array() As Double, ByVal long_array() As Double) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim angle As Double = 0
    Dim point1_lat As Double
    Dim point1_long As Double
    Dim point2_lat As Double
    Dim point2_long As Double
    Dim n As Integer = lat_array.Length()
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        point1_lat = lat_array(i) - latitude
        point1_long = long_array(i) - longitude
        point2_lat = lat_array((i + 1) Mod n) - latitude
        point2_long = long_array((i + 1) Mod n) - longitude
        angle += Angle2D(point1_lat, point1_long, point2_lat, point2_long)
    Next

    If Math.Abs(angle) < PI Then Return False Else Return True
End Function

Public Function Angle2D(ByVal y1 As Double, ByVal x1 As Double, ByVal y2 As Double, ByVal x2 As Double) As Double
    Dim dtheta, theta1, theta2 As Double
    theta1 = Math.Atan2(y1, x1)
    theta2 = Math.Atan2(y2, x2)
    dtheta = theta2 - theta1
    While dtheta > PI
         dtheta -= TWOPI
    End While

    While dtheta < -PI
        dtheta += TWOPI
    End While
    Return (dtheta)
End Function



 Public Function is_valid_gps_coordinate(ByVal latitude As Double, ByVal longitude As Double) As Boolean
        If latitude > -90 AndAlso latitude < 90 AndAlso longitude > -180 AndAlso longitude < 180 Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False
End Function
```