# Circlular Geofencing in c#.Net

Tags: c#, bing-maps, geofencing

I have drawn a circle in Bing maps. Now I need to write code for whether a point (latitude, longitude) is inside or outside of the circle?

Is there any algorithmic code in c#.Net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equation for testing if a point is inside a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle)

Comment: @Shai Not a duplicate. You don't compute distance for GPS coordinates with the sqrt(x²+y²) formula.

Comment: my bad. [this one fits better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287780/detecting-whether-a-gps-coordinate-falls-within-a-polygon-on-a-map)

Comment: Actually, if the radius of the circle is less than 20km or so then using Pythagorean doesn't have too much error.  You must first convert lat/long to Cartesian coordinates.  Haversine is generally faster if you don't already have Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compute the `distance between the center of the circle and your current coordinate`, and compare this distance to the circle radius (distance <= radius means the coordinate is inside the circle).

To compute the distance between two points, use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

You'll find a C# implementation [here](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe).

Comment: In Haversine formula, in which format we have to provide longitude and latitude. (Means in decimals or degress minutes seconds)

Comment: @GSReddy In the C# example I provided, the latitude and longitude are specified as decimal (`double` in C#), for instance 4.574554 (WGS84 system).

Comment: Is this distance returned is in kilometers or meters?

Comment: @GSReddy In the C# example I provided, you can choose between miles or kilometers

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine. Is there any idea how to implement Polygon geo fencing. I have googled it. I am getting alrogithums for convex polygons not for concave polygons. Suggest me.