# Are there some extensions for Google Maps Android API V2 for polygons?

Tags: android, polygon, android-maps-v2

I am using Google Maps V2 API for my android application, and I was wondering if there is an extension or something like that which I can use, that has an equivalent to Polygon.contains() function from V3?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you have not explained what `Polygon.contains()` actually does, I have no idea if [this set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287780/detecting-whether-a-gps-coordinate-falls-within-a-polygon-on-a-map) is relevant or not.

Comment: Oh sorry, completely forgot it. You give it coordinates of a point and it returns true if the point is in the polygon.

Comment: Then I'd take a look at the link from my initial comment.